# How to remove a subset of a data frame in Python?

Tags: python, pandas, subset

My dataframe df is 3020x4.
I'd like to remove a subset df1 20x4 out of the original. In other words, I just want to get the difference whose shape is 3000x4. I tried the below but it did not work. It returned exactly df. Would you please help? Thanks.

```
new_df = df.drop(df1)
```

Comment: What is this subset? is it a number of index values, specific values etc.?

Comment: Or are you just wanting to diff the 2 dfs? like `merged = df.merge(df1, indicator=True, how='left')` `merged[merged['_merge'] == 'left_only']`

Answer (score 18, accepted):

As you seem to be unable to post a representative example I will demonstrate one approach using `merge` with param `indicator=True`:

So generate some data:

```
In [116]:
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(5,3), columns=list('abc'))
df

Out[116]:
          a         b         c
0 -0.134933 -0.664799 -1.611790
1  1.457741  0.652709 -1.154430
2  0.534560 -0.781352  1.978084
3  0.844243 -0.234208 -2.415347
4 -0.118761 -0.287092  1.179237
```

take a subset:

```
In [118]:
df_subset=df.iloc[2:3]
df_subset

Out[118]:
         a         b         c
2  0.53456 -0.781352  1.978084
```

now perform a left `merge` with param `indicator=True` this will add `_merge` column which indicates whether the row is `left_only`, `both` or `right_only` (the latter won't appear in this example) and we filter the merged df to show only `left_only`:

```
In [121]:
df_new = df.merge(df_subset, how='left', indicator=True)
df_new = df_new[df_new['_merge'] == 'left_only']
df_new

Out[121]:
          a         b         c     _merge
0 -0.134933 -0.664799 -1.611790  left_only
1  1.457741  0.652709 -1.154430  left_only
3  0.844243 -0.234208 -2.415347  left_only
4 -0.118761 -0.287092  1.179237  left_only
```

here is the original merged df:

```
In [122]:
df.merge(df_subset, how='left', indicator=True)

Out[122]:
          a         b         c     _merge
0 -0.134933 -0.664799 -1.611790  left_only
1  1.457741  0.652709 -1.154430  left_only
2  0.534560 -0.781352  1.978084       both
3  0.844243 -0.234208 -2.415347  left_only
4 -0.118761 -0.287092  1.179237  left_only
```

Comment: index_to_keep = df.index.symmetric_difference(subset.index);df.loc[index_to_keep, :]

Comment: @PhilChang that assumes that the indices along with their contents are the same between the larger df and the subset, as the OP hasn't posted any sample data, here `merge` will just work as it will use the column values

Answer (score 16):

The [pandas cheat sheet](http://pandas.pydata.org/Pandas_Cheat_Sheet.pdf) suggests also the following technique

```
adf[~adf.x1.isin(bdf.x1)]
```

where x1 is the column being compared, adf is the dataframe from which the corresponding rows appearing in dataframe bdf are taken out.

The particular question asked by the OP can also be solved by

```
new_df = df.drop(df1.index)
```